# XSS (Cross Site Scripting) vs HTML Injection

Tags: javascript, html, xss, html-injections

How do we exactly differentiate betweet XSS and html injection. Both of these fall under Code-injection and XSS is mainly related to Java Script but includes other other elements also as mentioned [here on Mitre](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/79.html). Quoting from this source :

> During page generation, the application does not prevent the data from
>   containing content that is executable by a web browser, such as
>   **JavaScript, HTML tags, HTML attributes, mouse events, Flash, ActiveX,
>   etc.**

While HTML is mainly related to injecting HTML code and if i go through [this page of OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTML_Injection_(OTG-CLIENT-003)) it points out HTML injection as a type of XSS. Quoting from this source :

> If these methods are provided with an untrusted input, then there is
>   an high risk of **XSS, specifically an HTML injection one**.

On the other hand many sources claim that HTML injection is subset of XSS for example [this page of OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Cross_Site_Scripting). Quoting from this source :

> Cross-site scripting, better known as XSS, is in fact a **subset** of HTML
>   injection

There are sources trying to explain the differences between the two but none of them seems to be a satisfactory answer (rather they are controversial). 
So how exactly are they different ? Can one of them be treated as subset of the other ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no consensus in these sources. In the case where sources contradict eachother, you will have to make clear which definition you are using when working with the terminology.

Some sources seem to interpret XSS as Javascript injection ([1](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/html-injection/) and [2](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/html-injection/)), which then is similar to HTML injection. Both are mutually exclusive subsets of code injection under this definition.

Others will define XSS as code injection ([3](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTML_Injection_(OTG-CLIENT-003))), in which senario HTML injection is a subset of XSS.

Comment: Source [1](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/html-injection/) also says that HTML injection is subset of XSS : *“While in the XSS vulnerability the attacker can inject and execute Javascript code, the HTML injection attack only allows the injection of certain HTML tags.”*

Comment: I do not agree with that interpretation. "While A, B" indicates a contradiction in my world model. Also, when read in the context of the previous sentence, it is clear that the author does not mean that HTML injection is a subject of XSS: "HTML injection is an attack that is similar to Cross-site Scripting (XSS)"

Answer (score 0):

Xss is related to JavaScript however I agree that it includes HTML entities as well therefore considered as closely related to HTML injection but do note that mostly the payloads used by testers are for demonstration purpose only and not include the actual impact of the vulnerability and that's why they don't even contain much JavaScript. Also SOME HTML entities are important for breaking out of context but that doesn't makes it similar to HTML injection.